# Why I cannot trigger enhancements on jquery mobile widgets, when using jqmData to add attributes?

Tags: jquery, events, jquery-mobile, dynamic, delegates

I'm trying to create a fully dynamic 'jquery mobile' 'table widget'.

Problem is, JQM is using this to create different "table-modes":

```
$.mobile.document.delegate( ":jqmData(role='table')", "tablecreate", function(e) {
    // some magic happens here
});
```

In order to prevent automatic enhancement of the table, I'm excluding the triggering attribute `":jqmData(role='table')"` until my source code is ready. I then add the attribute and call this:

```
// tbody
target                   
    .empty()
    .append(allRows)
    // this enhances elements inside table rows
    .trigger("create")   
    .closest('table')
    // add triggering attribute
    .jqmData('role', 'table')
    // enhance the table (step 1 of 2)
    .table({
       create: function( event, ui ) {}
    })
```

This only gets me halfway, because now my table has the necessary attribute `":jqmData(role='table')"`, but I can't seem to trigger `tablecreate` on it.

I tried

```
    .trigger('tablecreate')
    .table({
       tablecreate: function( event, ui ) {}
    })
```

but they all do nothing, so I assume my element is not caught by the delegate-event binding (could be wrong, too).

**Question**:
In pure jquery, is it possible to include an element in a delegate handler, when I'm adding the triggering attribute at time X dynamically?

Thanks for inputs!

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Found it  myself:

The problem is:

```
 .jqmData('role', 'table')
```

does not seem to work all the time, as the `data-role="table"` will not be set when calling this.

I tried the following:

```
 .attr('data-role', 'table')
```

and the attribute was set and the table enhancement worked correctly.

Maybe helps someone else, too!